# How Create view in a database in server from tables presesnt in different database in diffrent server?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Let say i want to create a view named **'TestView'** in database **'test'** in server **'102.20.30.40'** from tables **'t1','t2','t3'** and **'t4'** present in database **'livedatabse'** in server **'190.50.60.70'**. How to create the view and how to get data from **'190.50.60.70'** in the **'102.20.30.40'** how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `federated` storage engine for that. Everything you need to know including examples is on this official manual pages: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Choose the MySQL version you're using in the upper right corner.

Comment: Sorry but i am still unclear how to do so and Its still not solving my problem.

Comment: What exactly is not clear? Have you read the manual? Here's a concrete example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-connection.html